# Php/mysql How to use Leading like wild card with additional query optimisations to speed the query?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I am actually trying to use leading wild card LIKE on a table's index (book_name), but it says indexed column should not use leading wild cards, slows down query. So now I am trying to use the leading wild card on its slug column instead. Slug is almost same like book_name but have to remove the hyphens between words in the slug.

```
select book_name,book_id from 
(select REPLACE(slug, '-',' ')
as tempslug 
from books) as T 
where tempslug like '%search words%'
order by book_name
```

P.S : @MadhurBhaiya, @alive to Die, Hi friends! The expected output are rows of booknames , but the book name should be searchable from between the book names: for example if have to find a book "My best book", then query should work for the word => best, or book, should return the "my best book" in results. It is doing, but I was hoping any other way or optimization to speed up the query, because I have used the leading wild card with indexed column.

Comment: **should not use** - it basically means that you will not get benefit of indexing. But you can still use the leading wildcard.

What is your sample table structure ? sample data ? expected output ?

Comment: so what's the problem here? query is not working? query gives wrong result? Please explain a bit more.`"indexed column should not use leading wild cards"`=> simply states that using wild-card will cut-down the benefit of indexing. It doesn't mean that you can't do that

Comment: What is `slug` field here ? What field is used to store bookname ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Hi friend! The expected output are rows of booknames, But I wish there was some optimization to speed up this query?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya slug  is the url field for every book stored in the database. It is unique field, almost same like book name, just having hyphens between the words. Bookname is stored in book_name field.

Comment: @LaReyna Depending on your MySQL version, and table engine, you could use [Full Text Searching](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-full-text-search.aspx)

Comment: @LaReyna Using slug to search for book names is not recommended at all! As it does not serve any benefits from indexing point of view.

Comment: you might get some performance improvement if you don't use a temporary table and instead do `where REPLACE(slug, '-',' ') like '%search words%'` however if you really want an optimized search you should be using something like [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/). Relational databases are not optimized for this type of searching

Comment: @apokryfos thanks for the tip, so I should completely modify my database for Fulltext feature?, right now I have Innodb mysql InnoDB system.

Comment: Right now each of my query takes 500-800ms time to complete via ajax requests, I wish I could reduce it to around  200-300ms time

Comment: The link by @MadhurBhaiya should help for that. I personally have not used MySQL for fulltext search before. However you can't have an index on a column that does not exist in the table so you probably should also store the result of `REPLACE(slug, '-',' ')` in a real column and index that as a fulltext index.

Comment: @LaReyna If you have MySQL version 5.7, Full text searching is supported in InnoDB as well

Comment: ok I tried without REPLACE(slug, '', '') in the query, But the results did not differ much, even wihout the temporary table the results are still similar, So i guess the leading wild card is the culprit :/

Comment: Ok I just checked I have mysql version 5.7, guess I will go through fulltext tutorials then, Thanks everyone for the great support :)